# Using Cache in android application

Tags: android, caching, image-caching

I've developing a android application and there's a feature in it that loads some images using asynctask. I think if i can save these images as cache i can boost the performance of the app as i am loading a lot of images. How can i do this? How can i keep cache in my android application?

My class

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    private ViewPageAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> filmCategory;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private FilmCategory category;
    private Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_fragment, container, false);

        fragment = this;

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();



        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.news_page_viewpager);

        dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity(),
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);


        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            filmCategory = JSONServices.getCategory();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setCategory(filmCategory);

            if (filmCategory != null) {

                pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(
                        fragment.getChildFragmentManager(), filmCategory,
                        activity);

                viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(activity, "No Active Internet Connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            dialog.dismiss();

            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // commonVariable.setFilmDetails((FilmCategory)
                    // category.getFilm().get(position));

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

    }
```

Comment: This might help: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are downloading images from server then i think Volley library help you out. it will remove boilerplate code and easy to read it support caching also. and if you want to implement cache then follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) link. and please avoid asyctask it will not survive config changes. use asynctaskLoader :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it might be easiest to use a third party library such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), or [Volley](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial)

I would check those out first before trying to implement your system for image caching. In most cases one of those three options will handle everything you need to accomplish.